# Why am I unable to add another Windows account on my phone?

Tags: microsoft-account, accounts

I am in Settings > Accounts > Email & app accounts. It shows

- Email & app accounts
- Email, calendar, and contacts
- [+] Add an account
- me@outlook.com

If I click on "Add an account" I encounter a bug with an infinite loop. It tells me it needs to send a code to verify my identity. I type in my alternate email address, get the code and enter it. But then it goes right back to the screen where it tells me it needs to send me a code. If I get another code and type it in it again tells me that it needs to send me a code. There is no error message(s), just an infinite loop.